# How to create a show more or show less toggleable button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble trying to make my code toggleable. I am able to press the button and it will show whatever content is hidden, however, when I try and press the button again, it won't hide the content. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
let toggle = document.querySelector('#chevron');

toggle.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  let press = toggle.value;

  if (press = "fas fa-chevron-right") {
    document.getElementById("content").classList = '';
    document.getElementById("chevron").innerHTML = 'SHOW LESS <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>';
  } else if (press = "fas fa-chevron-down") {
    document.getElementById("content").classList = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("chevron").innerHTML = 'MORE <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>';
  }

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="chevron" onclick="toggle"> SHOW MORE <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  <div id="content" class="hidden">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no value field exists on toggle
    `let press = toggle.value;` And Also You are assigning the value in if condition  `if (press = "fas fa-chevron-right")`instaed of comapre. Try it with some flag to make it toggle

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<details>` HTML element for that.

> The HTML Details Element (<details>) creates a disclosure widget in which information is visible only when the widget is toggled into an "open" state. A summary or label can be provided using the <summary> element.

More on the details element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

---

**Example:**

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2018.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are attaching two event handlers to the anchor element. First as an 'onclick' attribute event handler and also using the addEventListener method in js. I would recommend you to only use addEventListener and delete the 'onclick' handler.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are assigning the value `"fas fa-chevron-right"` to `press` within the `if` statement. The result of doing this is that it is always returns true.

Try something more like the following:

```
    let isOpen = false;

    document.getElementById("chevron").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()

      if (!isOpen) {
        document.getElementById("content").classList = '';
        document.getElementById("chevron").innerHTML = 'SHOW LESS <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("content").classList = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("chevron").innerHTML = 'MORE <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>';
      }
      isOpen = !isOpen;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many mistakes:

1. Only the form element(input, select, etc) has a valid property named value and it presents the actual content of the form. The value of Anchor is undefined.
2. In the event listener, you put the condition clause like if (press = "fas fa-chevron-right")  which doesn't work as expected because that it doesn't check whether variable press equals to 'fas fa-chevron-right'. It just assigns the right value to the press and the result always is the right value which will convert to true. So the first block has always been executed and the details show up.